# C++ Error_ expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token

Tags: c++

I am running a program to add vectors and I'm not sure why this error is coming, can someone please check my code and tell where it went wrong? Why is this `return []` in bold, should there be an index in the brackets?

```
#include<iostream>; #include<cmath>; #include<string>

double vector_length(double x, double y, double z);
double vector_add(double vectorA, double vectorB);

int main ()
{
    double l; double vector1[3][1];

    std::cout<<"Input x"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>vector1[0][0];
    
    std::cout<<"Enter y"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>> vector1[1][0];

    std::cout<<"Enter z"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>> vector1[2][0];

    double vector2[3][1];

    std::cout<<"Input x"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>vector2[0][0];

    std::cout<<"Enter y"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>> vector2[1][0];

    std::cout<<"Enter z"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>> vector2[2][0];

    double add_result[3][0]= vector_add_result(vector1,vector2)

    std::cout<<"vector addition"<<add_result<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}

double vector_add(double vectorA, double vectorB)
{

    double vector_add_result[3][1];

    for (int i=0, i<3, i++)
    {
        vector_add_result[i][0]= vector1[i][0]+vector2[i][0];
    }

    return vector_add_result[];
}
```

Comment: Please always include the full text of the error. We can't see on which line the error is highlighted

Comment: Besides you try to pass arrays, but you use just `double` number type, not `double[]` array of numbers type

Comment: `return vector_add_result[];` does not specify which element you want to be returned. To your question `should there be an index in the brackets?`: Yes!

Comment: What is point of having array with single item? Code obfuscation?

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems in your code. I will comment your code what is wrong and is not going to work and give you a working solution:

Includes are not seperated by semicolon. They need to be in one line each.

Wrong:

```
#include<iostream>; #include<cmath>; #include<string>
```

Correct:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
```

A 2D-array doesn't make that much sense if the second length of the array is only of size 1. C++ has an in-built array type which you can use instead:

Wrong:

```
double vector1[3][1];
```

Better:

```
std::array<double, 3> vector1;
```

You miss a semicolon on the following line. Also the  function you call does not exist, you probably mean `vector_add(...)`:

```
double add_result[3][0]= vector_add_result(vector1,vector2)
```

Instead you can do:

```
auto add_result = vector_add(vector1,vector2);
```

With that function:

```
std::array<double, 3> vector_add(const std::array<double, 3>& vector1, 
                                 const std::array<double, 3>& vector2)
{
    std::array<double, 3> vector_add_result;

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        vector_add_result[i]= vector1[i] + vector2[i];
    }

    return vector_add_result;
}
```

This function takes a reference to both input arrays and is returning the result also as an array.

Your main can then look like this with the improved code:

```
int main ()
{
    double l; 
    std::array<double, 3> vector1;

    std::cout<<"Input x"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>vector1[0];
    
    std::cout<<"Enter y"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>> vector1[1];

    std::cout<<"Enter z"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>> vector1[2];

    std::array<double, 3> vector2;

    std::cout<<"Input x"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>vector2[0];

    std::cout<<"Enter y"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>> vector2[1];

    std::cout<<"Enter z"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>> vector2[2];

    auto add_result = vector_add(vector1,vector2);

    std::cout<<"vector addition: "<< add_result[0] 
    << " "<< add_result[1] << " "<< add_result[2] 
    <<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I so support the promotion of std::array and std::vector!  For a lot of programs (and beginning programmers) that removes a lot of pain! Note :even the input could be factored out into a method still a lot of redundancy there. But nice example :)

Comment: @PKramer of course you are right. There is a lot of potential! I would start by creating a vector3D class and then overload the `+` and `<<` operator :D